# How set required constraint only for insert, not update in scaffold

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to set required constraint only for insert, not update. I know about using id in validator to distinguish insert/update, but how set required in validator and clear required field in dynamic scaffold generated view as well ?

To paraphrase it I can ask how check nullable and blank constraint inside validator closure ?

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is you can use the beforeInsert callback event...

```
class SomeDomain {
    int someProperty

    def beforeInsert() {
        if(someProperty != 42) {
            return false
        }
        true
    }
}
```

If `beforeInsert` returns false, the insert will be cancelled.  Depending on what you are really trying accomplish, that might help.  More info on GORM events is available at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Note that `beforeInsert` is separate from `beforeUpdate`.  If you only want this logic imposed on inserts, not updates, `beforeInsert` is the one to use.